# Javascript adding linebreak in mailto body

Tags: javascript, html

I'm setting the body of an email using values from a form

```
  firstname = bob
  lastname = dole

   ebody = 'First Name: ' + firstname + '\r\n' + 'Last Name: ' + lastname

  window.location.href = 'mailto:myemail@mycompany.com?subject=test
  email&body=' + ebody;
```

If I do an "alert(ebody);" I get the linebreak between firstname &
lastname, however when it opens up outlook, the entire ebody string
appears without a linebreak in the email body.

I've tried just \n also. is there something that can give be a line
break?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just an idea, did you try escaping the backslashes like `\\r\\n`?

Comment: did you try encoding the characters? -> `%0D%0A`

Comment: Is the MIME type text/plain for your e-mail?  Outlook might be trying to interpret as rich text.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[RFC 2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) says that mailto body content must be URL-encoded, using the %-escaped form for characters that would normally be encoded in a URL.  Those characters includes spaces and (as called out explicitly in section 5 of 2368) CR and LF.

You could do this by writing

```
ebody = 'First%20Name:%20' + firstname + '%0D%0A' + 'Last%20Name:%20' + lastname;
```

but it's easier and better to have JavaScript do the escaping for you, like this:

```
ebody = 'First Name: ' + firstname + '\r\n' + 'Last Name: ' + lastname;
ebody = encodeURIComponent(ebody);
```

Not only will that save you from having to identify and look up the hex values of characters that need to be encoded in your fixed text, it will also encode any goofy characters in the `firstname` and `lastname` variables.

Answer (score 9):

You can just use the Encoding  `%0D%0A` for line breaks.

```
firstname = 'Aung ';
lastname = 'Kyaw Zaw';

ebody = 'First Name: ' + firstname + '%0D%0A' + 'Last Name: ' + lastname;

window.location.href = 'mailto:myemail@mycompany.com?subject=testemail&body=' + ebody;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 2):

I would expect outlook to try and output this as html/rich text so in that case you would need something like the following (including a urlencoded br tag):

```
 firstname = bob
  lastname = dole

   ebody = 'First Name: ' + firstname + '%3C%2Fbr%3E' + 'Last Name: ' + lastname

  window.location.href = 'mailto:myemail@mycompany.com?subject=test
  email&body=' + ebody;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, when you're opening the outlook from a SharePoint content editor webpart using HTML/ JavaScript. then you need consider the following option as well.

use the code -

> %0D%0A%0D%0A

for a new line.

```html
<a href="mailto:jegan.baskaran@domain.de?subject=Hello%20there%20Mr%20Jegan&amp;body=Hello%20Jegan,%0D%0A%0DHowr%20are%20you%20boss.">E-Mail to Jegan</a>
```