# prevent extra space character inserted before new lines in javascript mailto:

Tags: javascript, encodeuricomponent

I have followed the recommended mailto: solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219781/javascript-adding-linebreak-in-mailto-body) in my javascript and am composing a mailto: directive as follows:

```
window.location.href = "mailto:?subject=test&body=" + encodeURIComponent( 'test' + '\r\n' + 'test' );
```

however, in two local mail clients - Outlook and iOS mail - it results in an extra space character right before the new line:

```
test 
test
```

How can I prevent this extra space from occurring?

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with the code. The space that you see in the end actually is not a space, but a `\r` character.

Comment: it happens if I remove the \r and just leave \n. it's definately a space. notepad++ shows: test[space][CR][LF]...

Comment: Yeah. I cannot be sure about how these characters are rendered. But you can open chrome's console, write `document.write(decodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent( 'test' + '\r\n' + 'test' )))`, and then observe the written content in the elements section of console. Try to move your cursor with keyboard. There is no space after the first `test`.