# How to add line break for plain text email client

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a line break after services in the mail client but I cannot find something that works

I have tried many things like `<br />`, `$#010;`, `\n`, `\n\r`
I have used these with double quotes in my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Save references to elements. Don't do DOM walks in event handlers when not needed.
    var $sendEmailEl = $('#send-email');
    var $subjectEl = $('#subject');
    var $bodyEl = $('#body');
    function getSelectedServices(){
        var services = "";
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i,cb){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                services += $(this).val() + "  |  ";
            }
        });
        return services;
    }
    function updateEmailLink() {
        console.log(getSelectedServices());
        $sendEmailEl.attr("href", "mailto:haghigsa@sheridancollege.ca?" +
            "subject=" + "Makeup Inquiry" + 
            "&body=" +"Selected Services: "+ getSelectedServices()+"\r\n "+ encodeURIComponent($bodyEl.val()));
        //console.log($sendEmailEl.attr('href'));
    }
    $('#subject,#body').on('input', updateEmailLink);
    updateEmailLink();
});
```

there are no errors, sometimes it will add the thing I typed into the email once the client opens (like 
 would just be included in text), most of the time it is ignored and does not even show up in the mail client

Comment: If the email is sent as HTML (which is _probably_ is) then `<br />` should suffice.  If RTF or plain-text than a simple `\r\n`\`\n` should do the trick. What's happening when you try these?

Comment: Try adding three spaces at the end of each line.

Comment: When i use \r\n or \n it's ignored(doesn't show up as text) and doesn't break the line, maybe because I am using mac?

Comment: My answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10220953/1334967 to a similar question should apply here.